# Maven : org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle

Tags: java, maven

---

I am working on a maven project having multiple sub-projects, In sub projects the project  weasis-core-ui, I have added some jars, which I want to use in the project.

I did that by adding the dependencies in pom.xml of weasis-core-ui: Following code is contains the dependencies, I am using
pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.rpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.xml.rpc</artifactId>
             <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
             <systemPath>E:/TestClient/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/axis.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>Disc</groupId>
            <artifactId>Disc-Id</artifactId>
             <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
             <systemPath>E:/TestClient/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-discovery-0.2.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>JXRPC</groupId>
            <artifactId>JXRPC-Id</artifactId>
             <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
             <systemPath>E:/TestClient/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/jaxrpc.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>SAAJ</groupId>
            <artifactId>SAAJ-Id</artifactId>
             <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
             <systemPath>E:/TestClient/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/saaj.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>WSDL</groupId>
            <artifactId>WSDL-Id</artifactId>
             <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
             <systemPath>E:/TestClient/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/wsdl4j.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>LOGGING</groupId>
            <artifactId>LOGGING-Id</artifactId>
             <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
             <systemPath>E:/TestClient/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

Cleaned the Projects, then Maven test, It works fine. 
But when I run the application, I am having this exception.

```
    27.05.2014 15:00:56.086 *INFO* [FelixStartLevel] org.weasis.core.api.internal.Activator Register Codec Plug-in: Sun java imageio
ERROR: Bundle weasis-core-ui [24] Error starting file:C:\Users\Taha-test\.m2\repository/org/weasis/core/weasis-core-ui/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/weasis-core-ui-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle weasis-core-ui [24]: Unable to resolve 24.0: missing requirement [24.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.rpc))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle weasis-core-ui [24]: Unable to resolve 24.0: missing requirement [24.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.rpc)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3984)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2045)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1299)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
27.05.2014 15:00:56.165 *INFO* [FelixStartLevel] org.weasis.core.api.internal.Activator Register Codec Plug-in: dcm4che
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle weasis-dicom-explorer [5]: Unable to resolve 5.0: missing requirement [5.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=it.cnr.imaa.essi.lablib.gui.checkboxtree)(version>=2.0.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 24.0: missing requirement [24.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.rpc)]
ERROR: Bundle weasis-dicom-explorer [5] Error starting file:C:\Users\Taha-test\.m2\repository/org/weasis/dicom/weasis-dicom-explorer/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/weasis-dicom-explorer-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle weasis-dicom-explorer [5]: Unable to resolve 5.0: missing requirement [5.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=it.cnr.imaa.essi.lablib.gui.checkboxtree)(version>=2.0.0)(!(version>=3.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 24.0: missing requirement [24.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.rpc)])
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3984)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2045)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1299)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Cannot not start framework: java.lang.Exception: Main User Interface bundle cannot be started
Weasis cache will be cleaned at next launch.
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right you have added the dependencies to weasis-core-ui and try to access it from weasis-dicom-explorer?

This is generally possible but considered bad practice (because it requires you to export packages that are not under your control). A better approach would be to define the interface of weasis-core-ui to rely on 3rd party dataclasses as little as possible. However it seems that even if it is correctly configured it doesen't work because weasis-core-ui also has a wiring issue.
Wiring exceptions occur when a bundle does not find all the packages it declares as dependency in its MANIFEST.MF file. In your case "javax.xml.rpc" is missing.

What comes now is tedious. You need to find out why weasis-core-ui actually requires javax.xml.rpc. If it turns out that the functionality that requires this package is actually not used by your code you can simply remove the import package directive for javax.xml.rpc and everything should work. If you indeed use the code that requires this, you will need to find a bundle that either exports that package or a jar that contains the package - Axis for example.

Now **how** you remove the import statement highly depends on how your MANIFEST.MF is managed. if you manage it by hand you can simply remove the line, if you manage it via the maven-bundle-plugin you need to alter your pom accordingly to exclude javax.xml.rpc.